# jquery or js code to obtain exact node data for currently selected form item/text/image in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to obtain the exact details for the item on a web page that has been clicked on, using jquery.

That item can be a form item (like a checkbox, text box, text area etc) or section of text (in a paragraph or div or other) or list or image ...

What I figured out is the following--

```
$(function(){
  $('*')
    .bind('click', function(event) {
        //now obtain details of item that has been clicked on...    

    });
});
```

Now, I want the exact details- viz the div id/form id/paragraph #, ie all details for that particular item. How do i get this data? I understand that this data is available in the DOM but I just dont know how to get it in this particular case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the target of click event on page

```
$(document).click(function(event){ 
  /* store native dom node*/
   var tgt=event.target;
  /* store jQuery object of dom node*/
   var $tgt=$(tgt);
    /* example element details*/
    var details={ id : tgt.id, height: $tgt.height(), tag : tgt.tagName}
    console.log( details)

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to do to use the `target` property of the event. By default, this returns a non-jQuery object, which isn't particularly useful, however wrapping it in `$()` solves this issue:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind('click', function(event) {
        var element = $(event.target);

        alert(element.height());    // Get height   
        alert(element.attr('id'));  // Get ID attribute
        // ...
    });
});
```

---

If you want to fix your current method, inside your `click()` handler, you can access the properties of that element using `.attr()`, and friends:

```
$(function() {
    $('*').bind('click', function(event) {
        alert($(this).height());    // Get height   
        alert($(this).attr('id'));  // Get ID attribute
        // ...
    });
});
```

`$(this)` in the scope of the function references the element that was clicked. There is a list of functions that will return attributes [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) in the jQuery docs. [`$.attr('id')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will return the element's ID, among other things, and `$.data()` will return `data-*` attributes.

To get attributes of parent elements, simply use `$(this).parent()`. For example, to get the ID of the form that contains the clicked element, use `$(this).closest('form').attr('id');`. Everything is relative to the clicked element (`$(this)`), so you can just use the [DOM traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

**However**, using `$('*').bind()` is *incredibly* inefficient; you're binding an event handler to *every* element on the page, when really you should delegate events with `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '*', function(event) {
        alert($(this).height());    // Get height   
        alert($(this).attr('id'));  // Get ID attribute
        // ...
    });
});
```

This approach only binds one event to `<body>` instead of an event to *every* element on the page.

Comment: i also want the id of the parent form/div as well... and what if the item is within a nested div (ie div within a div)? How do I get this complete data? Thanks...

Comment: using `event.target` is still far more efficient than searching every element in page to apply click handler

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `event.target`, and then you can use jQuery's `.parents()` method to look at every ancestor:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
     var $t = $(event.target); // the element that was actually clicked
     var $p = $t.parents();    // the target's parents

     var $form = $p.filter('form').first(); // the enclosing form, if it exists
});
```